# change child:before css when hover over parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As the title says it, I'm trying to change the childs:before css when a hover occurs over parent. I'm not having much luck

```
.ParentClass:hover .ChildClass:Before{
    color:#0000F;
}
```

**What I've tried:** The following all work but they are not what I'm looking for:

Changes child property but i'm trying to change child:before

```
.ParentClass:hover .ChildClass{
    color:#0000F;
}
```

This one changes when hover over child occurs while I want the change to happen when hover occurs over parent:

```
.ParentClass .ChildClass:hover:before{
    color:#0000F;
}
```

I can do this with javascript but I'm looking for pure CSS if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were so close on your first attempt. Instead of `Before`, you'll have to use `before` (lowercase). So, this will work just fine:

```
.ParentClass:hover .ChildClass:before {
    color: #00000F;
}
```

Anyway, if this doesn't work, please provide us the full HTML and CSS code, to support you further.

Comment: I was just about to write that.

Comment: also your color hex code is missing 1 value: #0000F_

Comment: @Liquidchrome You're right, I didn't notice that. I'll update the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: The case of `before` shouldn't matter.  The color syntax is the issue.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Yes, it seems like you have the correct answer. I didn't notice the color.

Comment: Thanks, just to quote the spec:  "Pseudo-element and pseudo-class names are case-insensitive."  From http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/selector.html#pseudo-elements

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your color syntax.  Use two hexadecimal digits per color (rgb):

Instead of this:

```
color: #0000F;
```

… do this:

```
color: #0000FF;
```

You could also do one hexadecimal digit per color:

```
color: #00F;
```

```css
.ParentClass:hover .ChildClass:Before {
  color: #0000FF;
}

.ChildClass:Before {
  content: 'Lorem';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="ParentClass">
    <span class="ChildClass">Ipsum</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Has An error on color hex:

Error:
color:#0000F;

Correctly:
color:#00000F;